# Error while adding a field of type array in quickblox custom object

Tags: quickblox, custom-object

I am trying to add a field with type "array of interger", but every time I try to create such field its giving error:

```
"Error An error occurred during request"
```

With the console error log: 
`"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"`

with stack trace as :

```
send qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:3
re.extend.ajax qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:3
t.fn.ajaxSubmit qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:11
e qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:11
re.event.dispatch qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
m.handle qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
re.event.trigger qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
(anonymous function) qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
re.extend.each qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:1
re.fn.re.each qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:1
re.fn.extend.trigger qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
re.fn.(anonymous function) qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:3
(anonymous function) qb.module.custom-1ebdde54a2ffba92919f740965d03db6.js:1
re.event.dispatch qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
m.handle qb.generic-92c8111bc4006f10fb3d0bcf2d9b3497.js:2
nrWrapper custom:11
```

I need to know what's wrong is going on at this end. Fields other than type "Array" are getting added normally. But I need to add an array for my application within the custom object.

Comment: This is solved by QuickBlox team today, everything is up and working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Also please let me know how can I add this custom parameter within existing dialogs, as I tried to update dialog and add this as:-

    `QB.chat.dialog.update(dialog_id, { data: {dialog_deleted_for: dialog_deleted_for_new}}, onDialogUpdated);`

But there is no such field created for the dialog id I sent.
Note: Dialog is of type "2" i.e a Group Dialog

Comment: please create a new question and provide more details on the issue, thanks

Comment: ok. Thanks for resolving the issue.

Comment: @IgorKhomenko, I have asked few other questions. Please reply over them, or guide me for them:


[Block Feature support for web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716188/quickblox-block-feature-support-for-web)
,

[Editing custom parameter value for a dialog using update Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713795/quickblox-editing-custom-parameter-value-for-a-dialog-using-update-dialog)